# How to upload image using retrofit in binary?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm working on a android app which post some user enter data with the user signature(Using signaturepad to capture signature and convert it into bmp file).

Now before posting whole data i need to request server to upload my canvas signature. so server will reply with two urls(refer image 1) which are put url and get url now I have to use PUT url to upload the signature image file and whole process is succeed with postman but i am unable to implement that on android app. Body of the Put URl is binary and I select some random image file.
For reference see the attached screenshots[image: Pre Requesting the server for uploading image].[image: Pre Request body][image: Put URL Params to upload image][image: Put url headers to upload image][image: Selecting an image as a binary body]

```
Retrofit retrofit_image_upload=new Retrofit.Builder()
                                        .baseUrl(Aws_url) // base url retrive using Uri class using uri.getAuthority and concat with "https:/"
                                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                                        .build();
```

```
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                signature.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);
                byte[] byteArray=stream.toByteArray();
                final RequestBody requestBody=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"),byteArray);
```

Now Calling api and passing data

```
                                Call<Object> image_upload_call= null;
                                try {
                                    image_upload_call = final_upload.aws_upload(path,auth,requestBody.contentLength(),x_amz_acl,AWSAccessKeyId,Expires,Signature_aws,requestBody);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
```

interface for uploading image

```
    @PUT("{Put_path}")
    Call<Object> aws_upload(@Path("Put_path") String path,
                            @Header("auth") String auth,
                            @Header("Content-Length") long length,
                            @Query("x-amz-acl") String x_amz,
                            @Query("AWSAccessKeyId") String awskey,
                            @Query("Expires") String Expires,
                            @Query("Signature") String Awssignature,
                            @Body RequestBody image);
}
```

When I using this code setup server doesn't accept the file from android app and reponse is error code 403 and when I try to upload image file from postman software it works fine. So how can I implement this into an android app.
Error from the server

```
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data preparation part code looks okay for me. But the URL you use for the PUT request is wrong.

As you mentioned in your question

> before posting whole data I need to request server to upload my canvas signature. so server will reply with two urls

That API is returning 2 URLs. From those 2 URLs, you select the second one to upload the file. I hope up to this point it works fine in the Android part.

Now, it's time to upload the file. You already got a fully qualified URL from API to upload the file. Just replace your `BASE_URL` with 2nd URL you got. Instead of using `@Path("Put_path")` annotation you should use `@Url` annotation. Like below,

```
@PUT()   /* remove "{Put_path}" parameter*/
Call<Object> aws_upload(
    @Url String path,   /* replace @Path() with @Url */
    @Header("auth") String auth,
    @Header("Content-Length") long length,
    @Query("x-amz-acl") String x_amz,
    @Query("AWSAccessKeyId") String awskey,
    @Query("Expires") String Expires,
    @Query("Signature") String Awssignature,
    @Body RequestBody image);
```

**Explanation**

1. How it works?

Let's say you want to hit the following URL

```
https://api.example.com/users/{user_id}
```

In Retrofit, you declare a `BASE_URL` and assign it with value `https://api.example.com/`. And in your service interface file, you declare a method like below

```
@GET("users/{user_id}")
Call<UserModel> fetchUserById(@Path("user_id") int userId);
```

Whenever you call the above method it'll build an URL like

```
https://api.example.com/users/100
```

From the above example what we learned is `@GET()`, `@POST()`, `@PUT()`, `@DELETE()` etc methods accept partial URL and the Retrofit client will generate the fully qualified URL for you.

2. What if you want to hit a URL other than BASE_URL from Retrofit client?

In that case, we use Retrofit's `@Url` annotation. It'll completely replace the BASE_URL for the current request.

I'll demonstrate the same above example but with `@Url` annotation.

```
@GET()  // notice the difference you don't need to pass partial path here
Call<UserModel> fetchUserById(@Url String url);
```

This time I'll hard code the fully qualified URL within the calling method or Activity/Fragment.

```
String overrideUrl = "https://api.example.com/users/200"; // prepare fully qualified url

SomeServiceInterface service = ...

Call<UserModel> call = service.fetchUserById(overrideUrl);  // pass it to method as an argument

call.enqueue(/* callback implementation here */);
```

Comment: you are passing url instead of path but i already create retrofit method with base url and i am passing the path everthing works fine url building is also works fine even server is also reposnding but here error is server doesn't acccept the file i am sending in android app, response from server is "signature" doesn't match which related to file type and file size. while requesting for put url i have to pass content type and content length so if these doesn't match while uploading image it throws same error i.e signature doesn't match.

Comment: I just referred the Postman screenshots from your question. In your question you only posted the uploading part code not the @PUT url request code. From Postman screenshots I can see that the api returns fully qualified upload url. You need to replace your BASE_URL with `@Url` annotation _only_ when you're uploading file. Did you check with the solution I mentioned in my answer? Does Retrofit receives 2nd URL successfully? If not please edit your question and post error logs and upload space request code as well. If not me someone else surely help you to get out from this problem. :)

Comment: My bad forget to include error from server, have a look I edited the body.